# Count changing values between successive rows and filter SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to a table which tracks versions of some devices. The table is used to track any version upgrades and the devices ping their version at different times in a day. Recently, I noticed that if a one user uses/signs up with another device then for the same user the table will have multiple versions pinging on the same day.Unfortunately, I can't change the underlying schema of this table or the logic to collect version pings into the different set of tables.

Now the issue is when the version upgrade happens to one of the devices, the table will show two different versions for a given day which is correct, however since the user has another device I get the version for that device as well.

My goal is to filter out any ids that have more than 1 device.Now in the below example Lets say 9.X is android device and all 1.X versions are ios.In that case id, 123 has two devices and I need to eliminate 123 from the dataset for further analysis. I need to track legit upgrades so in the below case only 234 and 345 are legit upgrades with 1 device.Though 123's first device upgraded ios from 1.6 to 1.7 I cannot include it in the analysis because 123 id has another device with android 9.0.

```
123    1.7    2017-08-11 22:57:54.307
123    9.0    2017-08-11 21:37:54.307 <-- 123 second device version
123    1.7    2017-08-11 20:27:54.307
123    1.7    2017-08-11 19:17:54.307 <-- 123 first device version upgrade
123    1.6    2017-08-11 18:47:54.307
123    1.6    2017-08-11 17:37:54.307
123    9.0    2017-08-11 16:57:54.307 <-- 123 signed up with a new device
123    1.6    2017-08-11 15:17:54.307 <-- 123 first device version

234    1.7    2017-08-11 22:47:54.307
234    1.7    2017-08-11 21:47:54.307 <-- 234 first device version upgrade
234    1.5    2017-08-11 20:47:54.307
234    1.5    2017-08-11 19:47:54.307
234    1.5    2017-08-11 18:47:54.307 <-- 234 first device version

345    1.8    2017-08-11 22:47:54.307
345    1.8    2017-08-11 21:47:54.307 <-- 345 first device version upgrade
345    1.4    2017-08-11 20:47:54.307
345    1.4    2017-08-11 19:47:54.307
345    1.4    2017-08-11 18:47:54.307 <-- 345 first device version
```

My script gives me the correct upgrades but does not filter those ids with more than 1 device.I need to do this in the first step so that I do not include 123 in the final dataset.

```
;with device_versions as
(
    select  id, 
            ver, 
            row_no = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by id order by MAX(dt_create) desc),  
            dt_create = MAX(dt_create),
            case
                when ver like '1.0%' then 'ios'
                else 'android'
            end device_name
    from dbo.version_history
    group by id, ver
)
select *,ios_row_no = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by min(dt_create) asc)
into #temp
from device_versions
where id in (select id from device_versions where row_no > 1 )
group by id,ver,row_no,dt_create,device_name
order by row_no

select id,ver,row_no,dt_create,device_name,ios_row_no
into #temp_final
from #temp a
where device_name='android' and   
ios_row_no = (select MAX(ios_row_no) from #temp b where a.id=b.id
and device_name='android')  

select a.id, dt_create = MIN(a.dt_create)
from #temp_final b
  JOIN dbo.version_history a
    ON  a.id = b.id
    AND a.dt_create > b.dt_create 
where  device_name ='android' 
group by a.id
union
select a.id, dt_create = MIN(a.dt_create)
from #temp b
  JOIN dbo.version_history a
    ON  a.id = b.id
    AND a.dt_create > b.dt_create
where  row_no = 2 and a.id not in (select id from #temp where device_name like 'ios')
group by a.id
union
select a.id,  MIN(a.dt_create)
from #temp b
  JOIN dbo.version_history a
    ON  a.id = b.id
where   a.id not in (select id from #temp where device_name like 'android')
group by a.id

drop table #temp
drop table #temp_final
```

**Current output** - I need to filter out 123 in the first step

```
123    
234    
345
```

**Expected output** - My script works for all ids with a single device and a legit upgrade.

```
234    
345
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using LEAD().

**1)**

```
select id,ver,lead(id,1) over (order by id,dt_create desc) as next_id,lead(ver,1) over (order by id,dt_create desc ) as next_ver,dt_create
into #temp1
from Z_version
order by id,dt_create desc

id  ver next_id next_ver    dt_create
123 1.7 123 9.0 2017-08-11 22:57:54.307
123 9.0 123 1.7 2017-08-11 21:37:54.307
123 1.7 123 1.7 2017-08-11 20:27:54.307
123 1.7 123 1.6 2017-08-11 19:17:54.307
123 1.6 123 1.6 2017-08-11 18:47:54.307
123 1.6 123 9.0 2017-08-11 17:37:54.307
123 9.0 123 1.6 2017-08-11 16:57:54.307
123 1.6 123 1.6 2017-08-11 15:17:54.307
123 1.6 123 1.6 2017-07-11 22:57:54.307
123 1.6 123 1.6 2017-07-11 21:37:54.307
123 1.6 123 1.6 2017-07-11 20:27:54.307
123 1.6 234 1.7 2017-07-11 19:17:54.307
234 1.7 234 1.7 2017-08-11 22:47:54.307
234 1.7 234 1.5 2017-08-11 22:47:54.307
234 1.5 234 1.5 2017-08-11 20:47:54.307
234 1.5 234 1.5 2017-08-11 19:47:54.307
234 1.5 234 1.5 2017-08-11 18:47:54.307
234 1.5 234 1.3 2017-07-11 22:47:54.307
234 1.3 234 1.3 2017-07-11 20:47:54.307
234 1.3 234 1.3 2017-07-11 19:47:54.307
234 1.3 345 1.8 2017-07-11 18:47:54.307
345 1.8 345 1.8 2017-08-11 22:47:54.307
345 1.8 345 1.4 2017-08-11 21:47:54.307
345 1.4 345 1.4 2017-08-11 20:47:54.307
345 1.4 345 1.4 2017-08-11 19:47:54.307
345 1.4 345 1.4 2017-08-11 18:47:54.307
345 1.4 NULL    NULL    2017-07-11 06:34:35.307
```

**2)**

```
select * into #temp2 from #temp1 where ver<>next_ver and id=next_id

id  ver next_id next_ver    dt_create
123 1.7 123 9.0 2017-08-11 22:57:54.307
123 9.0 123 1.7 2017-08-11 21:37:54.307
123 1.7 123 1.6 2017-08-11 19:17:54.307
123 1.6 123 9.0 2017-08-11 17:37:54.307
123 9.0 123 1.6 2017-08-11 16:57:54.307
234 1.7 234 1.5 2017-08-11 22:47:54.307
234 1.5 234 1.3 2017-07-11 22:47:54.307
345 1.8 345 1.4 2017-08-11 21:47:54.307
```

**3)**

```
select id,convert(varchar(12),dt_create,112) as each_day,count(ver) as ver_count into #temp3 from #temp2
group by id,convert(varchar(12),dt_create,112) order by id

id  each_day    ver_count
123 20170811    5
234 20170711    1
234 20170811    1
345 20170811    1
```

**4)**

```
select id,max(ver_count) max_count into #temp4 from #temp3 group by id

id  max_count
123 5
234 1
345 1
```

**5)**

```
select id,max_count from #temp4 where max_count < 2 

id  max_count
234 1
345 1
```

**6)**

```
drop table #temp1
drop table #temp2
drop table #temp3
drop table #temp4
```

Comment: Well Done!  Sorry I got pulled away +1

Comment: Thanks, having a discussion with you helped me reach the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, perhaps this will simplify it a bit.

**Example**

```
Select Top 1 With Ties *
 From  YourTable
 Where ID not in (Select ID From YourTable Group By ID having floor(min(ver))<>floor(max(ver)))
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition by id order by dt_create desc)
```

**Returns**

```
id   ver    dt_create
234  1.7    2017-08-11 22:47:54.307
345  1.8    2017-08-11 22:47:54.307
```

> **EDIT - Partioned by ID, date**

```
;with cte as (
Select *
      ,VerCnt = sum(1)   over (partition by id,cast(dt_create as date))
      ,VerMin = min(ver) over (partition by id,cast(dt_create as date))
      ,VerMax = max(ver) over (partition by id,cast(dt_create as date))
 From  @YourTable 
)
Select top 1 with ties
       id,ver,dt_create
 From  cte
 Where floor(VerMin)=floor(VerMax)
   and VerCnt>1
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition by id order by dt_create desc)
```

Comment: For a given day if there are more than 2 versions, I can assume that that id has another device i.e 1 did an upgrade and then there is another.The second way I can determine is  for a given day I get multiple version pings like x,y,x,y,x,y.The problem with the second one is anytime a device does a upgrade I am bound to have a x,y version combination.I just need to filter out users with more than 1 device in the first step.

Comment: Thanks,maybe if I count the number of times each ids version pings were different I can get 123 filtered.Like in the above case there are 5 version combination between successive rows for id 123 in a given day.1.6 -9.0, 9.0 -1.6,1.6-1.7,1.7-9.0 and finally 9.0-1.7.Maybe a combination of lag/lead on version?

Comment: @inquisitive_mind Perhaps the EDIT is closer to what you need.

Comment: What do you think about my solution below?